# Confusion on compressible 1D Euler Equations

Tags: fluid-dynamics, ideal-gas

Playing around with the 1D (and isothermal) steady state Euler equations and got some absurd results, so I am pretty sure I made a mistake somewhere.

Starting with continuity equation and momentum equations:

$$ v\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x} + \rho\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = 0   $$

$$ v\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} =-\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{\partial P}{\partial x}  $$

Assuming ideal gas:

$$ P =\rho RT $$

$$ \frac{\partial P}{\partial x} =\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x} RT $$

Substituting in the momentum equation:

$$ v\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} =-\frac{RT}{\rho}\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x}  $$

Multiplying the continuity equation by $v$:

$$ v^2\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x} + \rho v\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = 0   $$

And substituting the momentum equation onto it:

$$ v^2\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x} -\rho \frac{RT}{\rho}\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x} = 0   $$

Leading to the absurd results:

$$ \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x} \left( v^2 - RT  \right)  = 0   $$

$$ \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x}   = 0   $$

$$ v^2 = RT $$

So what's going on and where is the mistake? Thanks

EDIT: So it seems that the result above is possibly correct, however, I don't know if I am more or less confused.

Following the equations from [this link](http://mae-nas.eng.usu.edu/MAE_5420_Web/section3/section3.1.pdf) (NB: PDF), the integral form of the momentum and mass balances for 1d flow

$$\rho_1v_1 = \rho_2v_2$$

$$P_1 + \rho_1 v_1^2 = P_2 + \rho_2 v_2^2$$

$$\rho_1RT - \rho_2RT = \rho_2 v_2^2 - \rho_1 v_1^2$$

$$\rho_1RT - \frac{\rho_1v_1}{v_2}RT = \rho_1 v_1v_2 - \rho_1 v_1^2$$

$$\rho_1RT - \frac{\rho_1v_1}{v_2}RT = \rho_1 v_1v_2 - \rho_1 v_1^2$$

$$RT(v_2-v_1) = v_1v_2^2 - v_1^2v_2$$

$$RT(v_2-v_1) = v_1v_2(v_2-v_1)$$

Two solutions:

$$v_1=v_2; \rho_1 = \rho_2; P_1=P_2$$

$$v_1v_2 = RT ; P_1 = \rho_2 v_2^2; P_2 = \rho_1v_1^2 $$

This is almost the result from the differential equations, however the second one is different. And no less confusing to be honest. The first scenario has the variables not changing at all and the second has the velocity being independent of the pressure and depending on the value of $v_1 and v_2 $ the velocity on each end can easily reach relativistic values

For $v_1 = 1$ then $v_2 = RT$ which for nitrogen at room temp would be about 90000 m/s.

What does this all mean? Just absurd results because of the inviscid assumption?

EDIT 2: Just to clarify, the momentum Euler equation above does NOT assume incompressibility

the original equations on 1d are (as posted by Kyle Kanos)

$$ \partial_t \rho = -\partial_x(\rho v)$$

$$ \partial_t(\rho v) = -\partial_x(\rho v^2 + P) $$

$$ \rho \partial_t v + v \partial_t \rho = -\rho \partial_x(v^2) - v^2 \partial_x \rho -\partial_x P $$

$$ \rho \partial_t v + v \partial_t \rho = -2v\rho \partial_x(v) - v^2 \partial_x \rho -\partial_x P $$

$$ \rho \partial_t v + v \partial_t \rho = -v\rho \partial_x(v) - v\rho \partial_x(v) - v^2 \partial_x \rho -\partial_x P $$

$$ \rho \partial_t v + v \partial_t \rho = -v\rho \partial_x(v) - v(\rho \partial_x(v) - v \partial_x \rho) -\partial_x P $$

$$ \rho \partial_t v + v \partial_t \rho + v(\rho \partial_x(v) + v \partial_x \rho)  = -v\rho \partial_x(v)  -\partial_x P $$

$$ \rho \partial_t v + v \partial_t \rho + v(\partial_x(\rho v))  = -v\rho \partial_x(v)  -\partial_x P $$

$$ \rho \partial_t v + v(\partial_t \rho + \partial_x(\rho v))  = -v\rho \partial_x(v)  -\partial_x P $$

Term inside the parenthesis on the LHS is the continuity equation, so it vanishes:

$$ \rho \partial_t v + v\rho \partial_x(v) = -\partial_x P $$

$$  \partial_t v + v \partial_x(v) = -\frac{\partial_x P}{\rho} $$

And the steady version:

$$  v \partial_x(v) = -\frac{\partial_x P}{\rho} $$

$$ v\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} =-\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{\partial P}{\partial x}  $$

Which is the same equation on the beggining.

This is valid on general 3D problem as well, the derivation can be found here:

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivation_of_the_Navier–Stokes_equations#Conservation_of_momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivation_of_the_Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations#Conservation_of_momentum)

and the compressible euler equations i took directly from here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_equations_(fluid_dynamics)#Euler_equations

Comment: Why is the result absurd?

Comment: It implies that for 1D flow $ \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x} = 0   $ for every boundary problem in and/or that the speed of the flow goes well above the speed of sound(after substitution of common values for R an T). Is this correct?

Comment: It's not much of a "flow" if $\partial_tv=\partial_xv=0$, right? Kind of stationary fluid at that point.

Comment: Yeah, for whatever boundary conditions you put, the velocity everywhere would be the same. This is really odd to me because it renders the entirety of the BVP of the 1D euler equations already solved and this result doesn't quite match the formulas here:http://mae-nas.eng.usu.edu/MAE_5420_Web/section3/section3.1.pdf

Comment: It also doesn't quite match the compressible bernoulli equation either...

Comment: I don't see where your link assumes constant temperature, as you do.

Comment: Does it matter? Because the momentum, mass and energy equations are independent. Assuming constant temperature only simplifies some stuff. The constant temperature scenario is a particular case of the general equations of the link... I will play around with them to see if i can get the same result, but from first sight they don't...

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$v\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=\frac{1}{\rho}\,\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}$$
requires that the fluid be incompressible, which seemingly contradicts with the use of $\partial_x\rho$ in the continuity equation. You should be starting with the 1D Euler equation as,
\begin{align}
  \partial_t\rho &= -\partial_x(\rho v) \tag{1a}\\
  \partial_t(\rho v)&= -\partial_x(\rho v^2+p)\tag{1b}
\end{align}
and then asserting steady state & applying the ideal gas and continuity equations.

The source you're looking at is identifying the [*Rankine-Hugoniot conditions*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rankine%E2%80%93Hugoniot_conditions) by looking at the RHS of Eq (1) across the boundary of two fluid parcels (usually on opposite sides of a [shock interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shock_wave)):
\begin{align}
  \left.\partial_x(\rho v)\right]_{1}^2 &\to\rho_1v_1=\rho_2v_2\\
  \left.\partial_x(\rho v^2+p)\right]_1^2 &\to\rho_1v_1^2+p_1=\rho_2v_2^2+p_2
\end{align}
Since shocks are able to travel faster than the speed of sounds (cf. the [Mach number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach_number)), that a speed of sound is exceeded here may not be surprising.

Comment: Pretty sure the euler equations as is is valid for compressible or incompressible alike. The most general form of the momentum equation: The cauchy equations of motion, has the density outside the material derivative https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_momentum_equation . The partial derivatives of density will vanish due to the continuity equation itself. You can show that for a mass conserving system $D(\rho k)Dt = \rho DkDt$ where k is an arbitrary property. You can see how even in the integral form of the momentum equation the same weird result appears

Comment: You can see that the partial derivatives of the density in the momentum equation vanish on this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivation_of_the_Navier–Stokes_equations

Comment: Just for another sanity check: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_equations_(fluid_dynamics)#Euler_equations Also has the euler equations in the same form as i wrote (if considered 1d only)

Comment: What I'm saying is that you are using a momentum equation that assumes incompressibility and comparing it to a compressible flow; any inference you make from that is more or less nonsense. I'm advocating that you start from a compressible system of equations and assert incompressibility laster on, if the system later requires it.

Comment: The equation does not assume incompressibility... Did you check the links i posted?

Comment: It is only possible to go from $\partial_x(\rho v^2+p)$ to $v\partial_xv=(\partial_xp)/\rho$ if $\partial_x\rho=0$. If you want to call that something other than "incompressible", fine. The mistake is still there: you're asserting from the onset that $\partial_x\rho=0$ while elsewhere expecting $\partial_x\rho\neq0$ and assuming something sensible should occur.

Comment: $\partial_x (\rho v^2 + p)) = \rho \partial_x(v^2) + v^2\partial_x(\rho) + \partial_x p = 2\rho v \partial_x(v) +  v^2\partial_x(\rho) + \partial_x p = \rho v \partial_x(v) + v(v \partial_x(\rho) + \rho\partial_x(v)) +  \partial_x p $ Term inside the parenthesis is the steady continuity equation, it vanishes, thus: $ \rho v \partial_x(v)  + \partial_x p = 0$

Comment: Formatting on the side comments is hard, i will post another reply. no $\partial_x \rho = 0 $ is required to use the euler equations of the op. You can see the derivations on the two links i posted...

Comment: Please see the last edit. I hope i clarified that no incompressibility in any form is assumed...

Answer (score 0):

I think the question can be closed, i found that the answer by user Ján Lalinský in the question

[Steady isothermal flow of an ideal gas](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/82869/steady-isothermal-flow-of-an-ideal-gas?rq=1)

Answers the question rather concisely and, indeed, the Pressure and Velocity are to be constant everywhere in a inviscid 1D, steady and isothermal flow of an ideal gas.